# How to convert a XFile to File in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to convert an XFile to File to upload the file to Firebase since Firebase only uploads in File format.
The code is as follows:

```
XFile videofile;
videofile = file;
await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(imageRef).putFile(videoFile);
```

Gives an error saying XFile can't be uploaded to Firebase

Using XFile package from [XFile package](https://pub.dev/packages/xfile) gives another error saying:

*The name 'XFile' is defined in the libraries 'package:cross_file/src/types/interface.dart' and 'package:xfile/src/xfile_core.dart (via package:xfile/xfile.dart)'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.*

other dependencies in the file are

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
File file = File(videofile.path);
```

.toFile() may not work because XFile plugin may conflict with another plugins

Comment: Just in case someone else encounter this. I accidentally imported from 'dart:html', should import from 'dart:io' instead.

Answer (score 27):

To convert your Xfile image to File image to show the image inside the widget you can use:

```
XFile? selectedImage;

Image.file(File(selectedImage!.path))
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone facing challenges with the network-type path returned by `xFile.path`, which cannot be used to create a file, you can instead use the FireStore `putData` function and read in the xFile as bytes.

```
FirebaseStorage store = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final _picker = ImagePicker();
XFile? pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      TaskSnapshot task = await store.ref(imageRef).putData(await pickedImage.readAsBytes());
    }
```

It's always a good idea to compress images where necessary before handling/processing.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
final file = videofile.toFile();
```

You can find more examples in plugin's docs [here](https://pub.dev/packages/xfile).

Answer (score 0):

```
File convertToFile(XFile xFile) => File(xFile.path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _image34 = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxWidth: 200.0, maxHeight: 200.0);

FirebaseStorage fs = FirebaseStorage.instance;

Reference  rootReference = fs.ref();

Reference pictureFolderRef = rootReference.child("pictures").child("image");

pictureFolderRef.putFile(File(_image34!.path)).whenComplete(() => print("uploaded")).then((storageTask) async {
  String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello, here is the answer for those who have updated libraries today (08/26/2021).

```
XFile videofile;
videofile = file;
await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(imageRef).putFile(File(videoFile!path));
```

Please notify if it helped, thank you.

Comment: what kind of file would this store? jpg/png/gif?